# I want to create a method in apex to check if the date format is in 'mm/dd/yyyy'

Tags: apex, datetime, date

I have created this but getting an error>> "Condition expression must be of type Boolean: String"

```
public static boolean validateDateFormat(String date1){
    DateTime validDate  = DateTime.valueOf((date1);
        if(validDate.format('mm/dd/yyyy')){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
        
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the documentation for the format, its return type is String. and as error message is depicting the if conditions requires TRUE/FALSE.

Also please add the negative scenarios in the methods(what if string is not date).

**Documentation link -**
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm

A rough code for checking pattern is -

```apex
String regex = '[0-9]{0,2}/[0-9]{0,2}/[0-9]{4}';
Pattern datePattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matchDate = datePattern.matcher('1/11/2020');
System.assert( matchDate.matches() == true);
matchDate = datePattern.matcher('1/111/2020');
System.assert( matchDate.matches() == false);
```